# VB.NET Login Attempts using Count

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure out to do these logic. Example: if user input incorrect values 3 times, he will get a message like too much attempts and should not be able to type anything in 10 sec, after that he should be able to login again. I'm a beginner in vb.net and kinda lost here. I hope someone would be able to help me in my problem

PS: I think the possible way in my logic is by using Timer for the seconds but don't know how to construct it below my code

```
 Private Sub btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click

    Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from user_access where Username= @user AND Password= @pass", con)
    command.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_username.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_password.Text
    con.Open()
    reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    While (reader.Read())
        count = count + 1
    End While

    If (count = 1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully")
        LoginForm1.Hide()
        MainForm.ShowDialog()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username/Password")

    End If
    If count = 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Too Many Logins")
    End If
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You are counting how many users you got with the password in your database. Normally, count should be 0 or 1 in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a timer to your code, either through a designer or at class level, and set it's interval to 10000 (10s).

Activate your timer on 3rd failure like so:

```
If count = 3 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Too Many Logins. Disabled for 10s")
    btn_login.Enabled = False
    LockoutTimer.Start()
End If
```

Then you need to handle the timer completion:

```
Private Sub LockoutTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LockoutTimer.Tick
    LockoutTimer.Stop()
    btn_login.Enabled = True
    count = 0
End Sub
```

As muffi mentioned in comments your logic is off for checking login. Currently you check how many users match the given username and password combination. You need to check the existence and increment a separate variable if login was unsuccessful:

```
Dim loginSuccess As Boolean = False
While (reader.Read())
    loginSuccess = True
End While

If (loginSuccess) Then
    count = 0
    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully")
    LoginForm1.Hide()
    MainForm.ShowDialog()
Else
    count += 1
    If count = 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Too many invalid login attempts. Disabled for 10s")
        btn_login.Enabled = False
        LockoutTimer.Start()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username/Password")
    End If 
End If
```

Note: The count variable needs to persist across button clicks, so make it a field in the class and reset on successful login (if required)

```
Private count As Integer = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for this sir. I encountered something when it goes to 3 times attempt, 2 messagebox is appearning the first one is the invalid username/pass then the second one is Too Many Logins. Disabled for 10s but it solves my logic THANK YOU

Comment: @Miracle I've made a quick update to avoid the double messagebox, and also reset the count once the button reenables